# The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG 6494C6D6997C215E Google Inc despite correct signing key

Tags: google, apt

Ubuntu (focal 20.04)

Using [Google webdesigner apt repository](https://www.google.com/linuxrepositories/) in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-webdesigner.list`:

```
deb [arch=amd64] https://dl.google.com/linux/webdesigner/deb/ stable main
```

leads to:

```
# wget -q -O - https://dl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | sudo apt-key add -
OK
# apt-key list | grep -C 2 "Google Inc"
Warning: apt-key output should not be parsed (stdout is not a terminal)
pub   rsa4096 2016-04-12 [SC]
      EB4C 1BFD 4F04 2F6D DDCC  EC91 7721 F63B D38B 4796
uid           [ unknown] Google Inc. (Linux Packages Signing Authority) <linux-packages-keymaster@google.com>
sub   rsa4096 2019-07-22 [S] [expires: 2022-07-21]

# gpg --list-keys | grep -C 2 "Google Inc"
pub   rsa4096 2016-04-12 [SC]
      EB4C1BFD4F042F6DDDCCEC917721F63BD38B4796
uid           [ unknown] Google Inc. (Linux Packages Signing Authority) <linux-packages-keymaster@google.com>

# apt update
...
Err:14 https://dl.google.com/linux/webdesigner/deb stable Release.gpg
  The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG 6494C6D6997C215E Google Inc. (Linux Packages Signing Authority) <linux-packages-keymaster@google.com>
...
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: https://dl.google.com/linux/webdesigner/deb stable Release: The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG 6494C6D6997C215E Google Inc. (Linux Packages Signing Authority) <linux-packages-keymaster@google.com>
...
```

I have been seeing this error only for a few days.
Does anyone know what is suddenly going on?

Answer (score 1):

"**This is the protection you are getting from these checks.** You don't want to update your software right now while something is messed up on Google's end. Wait until they fix it. Don't try to override by reinstalling keys until some official word comes out that a new key is the solution."

[Original link - Source](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1133199/the-following-signatures-were-invalid-expkeysig-1397bc53640db551)

Comment: Welcome to the site, Cesar! That's a helpful link, though it is from nine months ago. If Google still didn't fix it, I expect they never will and waiting may not be the solution to the problem.

Comment: The link refers to a different key, though, and that one was eventually renewed as you can see behind the link. I came here because the same key as in the OP is also used for signing the Music Manager. I hope we are lucky and Google replaces that one after a week as well.